# pymongo - Search collection for documents that contain with $and operator case insensitive

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying to search a collection which contains documents, collection looking like this:

```
[{'description':'Fast and Dangerous',
'colour':'blue',
'make':'ford'},
{'description':'slow and dangerous',
'colour':'red',
'make':'lexus'}]
```

I am trying to build a search query that will return all the documents which contain Red and Dangerous (case insensitive)

I started off with:

```
find({"$text": {"$search": "red dangerous"}})
```

However, this is certainly case insensitive, but it is an OR rather than AND.

I have read through https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and - but it means you have to refer to specific fields which could contain Red or Dangerous, rather than the entire document.  What's the best way to go about this?  I want my code to be professional, and I feel whatever hack I come up with really won't be. Any pointers?

Comment: Use `$meta` aggregation with the `$sort` stage. Something like `db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { $text: {"$search": "red Dangerous"} } },
     { $addFields: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
     { $sort: { score: 1 } }
   ]
)`. The text score signifies how well  the document matched the search term or terms. So the best matched documents will always come on the top.

Comment: That's a really interesting answer.  Certainly highlighted some features I wasn't aware of.  I'll put it in.  It feels like my request should have a definite answer though, as in all of the 
requirements of the search have been met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can use [**`$meta`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/meta/#exp._S_meta) aggregation with the [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage. Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "$text": { "$search": "red Dangerous" } } },
  { "$addFields": { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } } },
  { "$sort": { "score": 1 } }
])
```

The text score signifies how well the document matched the search term or terms. So the best matched documents will always come on the top.